# MySQL - top product exported by each state based on the sum of individual export_values

Tags: mysql, peewee

I am trying to write a query in Peewee with a MySQL database to return the top `product` exported by each `state` based on the sum of the `export_value`s for a given product-state pair. I am wondering what the most optimal SQL query to achieve that would be. Here's the schema of the table I care about:

```
Trade
- product (varchar)
- state (varchar)
- export_value (numeric)
...
```

The fields I need to select are: `state`, `product`, and `total_export_value`.

Any guidance on how to design this query? If possible, also on how to translate it into Peewee (I am very new to it).

## EDIT:

Here's the Peewee query I've tried:

```
    subquery = (
        models.Trade.select(
            models.Trade.state.alias("state_1"),
            models.Trade.product.alias("product_1"),
            fn.SUM(models.Trade.export_value).alias("export_value_1")
        ).where(
            models.Trade.origin_country == origin_country,
            models.Trade.year == args["year"]
        ).group_by(
            models.Trade.state,
            models.Trade.product
        ).alias("subquery")
    )

    query = (
        models.Trade.select(
            models.Trade.state,
            models.Trade.product,
            fn.MAX(subquery.c.export_value_1).alias("export_value")
        ).join(
            subquery, on=(
                (models.Trade.state == subquery.c.state_1) &
                (models.Trade.product == subquery.c.product_1)
            )
        ).group_by(
            models.Trade.state
        )
    )
```

It's not working for my needs because MySQL is not selecting the appropriate `product`, but the `state` and `total_export_value` are selected just fine. I suspect it's because of the way it's joining the two queries and that `product` is not used in the GROUP BY of the `query`.

Comment: Nobody will be able to geuss the query you need without table structure, example data (place it on http://www.sqlfiddle.com) and expected output as ascii data table

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Sorry Sloan! I added more details to the question.

Comment: Do you actually need that final "group by"? Can you delete it from the outer query?